# Collision Broadening - Spontaneous emission

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, atomic-physics, quantum-optics, photon-emission

I am currently reading Loudon's "The Quantum Theory of Light" and get stuck about the following sentence:

> Consider a particular atom radiating light of frequency $w_0$ . A train of
> electromagnetic radiation emanates steadily from the atom until it suffers a
> collision. During a collision, the energy levels of the atom are shifted by amounts
> that depend on the severity of the collision, and the radiated wave train is interrupted for its duration. The wave of frequency $w_0$ is resumed after the
> collision, its characteristics are identical to those that it had prior to the collision,
> except that the phase of the wave is unrelated to the phase before the collision.

I don't get the first sentence: How can **a particular (i.e. single)** atom radiate light for a prolonged period of time? In my understanding:

1. An single atom in an excited state undergoes a transition to the ground state with a certain probability $\Gamma$ per unit time: $|c_e(t)|^2 \propto e^{\frac{1}{\Gamma} t}$. This means that after some time $\tau$, the atom has emitted a single photon, let's say at a time $t_0$. That means that before and after this time $t_0$, no radiation was/is emitted.
2. In the book, we assume that the atom emanates *steadily* for the whole period $\tau$. How can this be, given that the event of spontaneous emission happens at one specific point in time and is not distributed, so to say, over the entire interval?

Question summary: I do not understand how to reconcile the fact that spontaneous emission happens at a given point in time with the fact that the atom emanates light steadily, and can even undergo collisions during that time.

Comment: Do you by any chance think that it is possible that the atom(s) is(are) also emanated with light with some energy so that it is possible for it(them) to gain and lose energy repeatedly?

Comment: @Newbie That surely is possible in general, but not mentioned anywhere in the book. So should "atom steadily emanates light" be interpreted as "atom emits photons and gets re-excited?"

Comment: I’m gonna take a look at that part of the book before commenting on it. Interesting question though.